# If $a_n\to1$, $(a_n)$ positive increasing, and $\sum \frac 1n (1-a_n^n)$ converges, then $a_n^n \to 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_n$ be an increasing sequence of positive real numbers converging to $1$ such that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1n (1-a_n^n) < +\infty. $$
Is it necessarily true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^n = 1$?

Comment: Detail: The title doesn't quite match the question.

Comment: @ClementC. Oh, I am very sorry. I though that I can restate the question in a simpler way (forgetting to change the title), but of course I can not. Thanks!

Comment: Assume that $a_{u(n)}^{u(n)}\leqslant c^{2}$ with $c<1$ for every $n$, for some subsequence $(u(n))$ such that $u(n)\geqslant 2u(n-1)$ for every $n$. Then, for every $\frac{1}{2}u(n)\leqslant k\leqslant u(n)$, $a_{k}^{k}\leqslant a_{u(n)}^{k}\leqslant c^{2k/u(n)}\leqslant c$ and $$\sum_{k=u(n-1)}^{u(n)}\frac{1}{k}(1-a_{k}^{k}) \geqslant \sum_{k=u(n)/2}^{u(n)}\frac{1}{k}(1-a_{k}^{k}) \geqslant (1-c)\sum_{k=u(n)/2}^{u(n)}\frac{1}{k} \to (1-c)\log2>0,$$ hence the series diverges. By contraposition, if $\sum\limits_n\frac{1}{n}(1-a_n^n)$ converges then $a_n^n\to1$.

Comment: @Did Many thanks! Great. Just one question: do you really need to assume that $u(n) \ge 2u(n-1)$? If the series converges, then $\sum_{u(n)/2}^{u(n)}$ converges to $0$, isn't it?